# Informatica: holding multiple result in multiple variable

Tags: informatica

I have scenario where i am calculating value as below
Count= IIF(Condition = true, Var1+1,Var2)

Var1= when Count <>0 than store value in Var1(how to wtite that condition in informatica for Var1)
Var2=0

how to wtite that condition in informatica for Var1 and i would retain that value for multiple rows to process.

Comment: Not able to understand if you deriving count from var1 or var1 from count. Could you tell us what u r trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hold values across rows, in the expression transformation define that port as variable port.